# round corners and color border on html form elements

Tags: html, forms, coding-style

how can i make cool **check-box** and **select-box** elements in html form ,
that work in `IE`  too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is usually done is to create a fake element that (via javascript) sets the value to a hidden element (hidden via css). Then this fake element can have any visual style applied to it.

- [Creating custom styled checkboxes with jQuery](http://john.mcclumpha.org/javascript/Creating_custom_styled_checkboxes_with_jQuery/)

Comment: thanks its help i found something to select box :
http://www.brainfault.com/2008/02/10/new-release-of-jquery-selectbox-replacement/

Comment: FWIW, this is a horrible, horrible idea to begin with. First of all, there are reasons as to why you can't skin checkboxes and other form elements properly. Secondly, anything that claims to skin your checkboxes is nothing but an awful hack that should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: i found a jquery plugin 
http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/

Comment: That's pretty neat :) But you're just abstracting the "hidden" elements away with this plugin :) Check the generated source code (via web developer in firefox) and see.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes and radiobuttons can't be styled (consistently) every browser displays them in their own way, and some browsers ignore the styles set to them completely.

What Ólafur Waage said (creating a fake element via javascript) is the most common way of doing it as far as i know.